# probability of the product of drawn numbers is positive

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have just started learning probability in class, and have done one lesson on basic combinatorics, I'm going through some practice questions and have stumbled upon a few.

The first is:

> A box contains $20$ numbers, of which $8$ are negative and $12$ are positive. If $6$ numbers are picked without replacement, find the probability their product will be positive.

Rough solution I have so far: probability of the product being positive is 
$$ \frac{\binom 6{12}}{\binom 6{20}}$$

Am I headed in the right direction ?

Comment: negative times negative is also positive

Comment: You need to sort the various ways the product might be positive.  You've looked at "all six positive", but there are other cases.

Answer (score 1):

First count the number of total ways to pick the $6$ numbers. Since you have $20$ to choose from, this is simply $\dbinom{20}{6}.$

Now count the successful ways using casework. To end up with a positive number, you can have all negative, $2$ positive and $4$ negative, $4$ positive or $2$ negative, or all positive. Using summation notation, this count is
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{3}\dbinom{12}{2n}\dbinom{8}{6 - 2n}.$$

If we evaluate that summation, we get a total of $19,432$ ways to have a positive product.

Our probability is $P = \frac{19,432}{\dbinom{20}{6}} = \boxed{\frac{2429}{4845}}.$

Comment: Does your sum count the "all positive" case?  If the upper limit is $n=2$ then it looks like you only consider $0,2,4$ positive numbers.